# SocketAsyncEventArgs. Событие закрытия UDP сокета пользователем

Tags: c#, uwp, udp

Я понимаю, что udp доставляет сообщения без подтверждения. Возможно ли повесить событие, когда пользователь закроет подключение???

Answer (score 1):

Нет, невозможно. Уведомления о закрытии в протоколе не предусмотрено.